# Information Extraction -> Relationships

Tags: information-extraction

"The movie was amazing. The background music was eccentric and the lighting was perfect"
Movie:Amazing
Background Music:Eccentric
Lighting:Perfect

How viable is this in C#?

I'm using the stanford NLP library but I don't have a clue on how I'd do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html which is a .Net port of CoreNLP, though I'm not sure how up-to-date it is.

You are basically doing POS tagging: finding the adjective associated with the noun.

You can try your text here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

[image]

Get your POS model from CoreNLP, find the nouns (NN) that you're interested in, and get their corresponding adjectives (JJ)